# Using sample2D as position in vertex shader

Tags: webgl

I'm learning how to manipulate particles with FBO in webGL, I tried to store the position with a texture and use it a position reference, but nothing came up on the stage.

*Fragment Shaders*

```
precision mediump float;

void main() {

gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(1.0), 1.0);

}

</script>
```

*Vertex Render Shader script*

```
attribute vec2 aTextureUV;
uniform sampler2D uTexture;

void main() {
vec4 texture = texture2D( uTexture, aTextureUV );
gl_Position = vec4( texture.rgb, 1.0 );
gl_PointSize = 3;
}

</script>
```

*JS Script*

```
// Determine the UVs
var uvs = new Float32Array([
0.0, 0.0,
1.0, 0.0,
0.0, 1.0,
1.0, 1.0
])

var uvBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, uvBuffer );
gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, uvs, gl.STATIC_DRAW );
gl.enableVertexAttribArray( defaultProgram.aTextureUVLoc );
gl.vertexAttribPointer( defaultProgram.aTextureUVLoc, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

// Texture initialization
for(var i = 0; i < particleCount; i++) {
            initialData.push(
                Math.random(),
                Math.random(),
                Math.random(),
                0
            );
        }

var texture = gl.createTexture();
gl.activeTexture( gl.TEXTURE0 );
gl.bindTexture( gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture );
gl.pixelStorei( gl.UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1 );

gl.texImage2D(
gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, fboWidth, fboWidth, 0,
gl.RGBA, gl.FLOAT, new Float32Array(initialData)
);

gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);

.....


function draw() {

   requestAnimationFrame( draw );

   gl.viewport( 0, 0, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight );
   gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
   gl.drawArrays( gl.POINTS, 0, particleCount );
}
```

Comment: Why not in a buffer ?

Comment: are you talking about the texture? does it automatically attach itself to the context, when you use gl.bindTexture? because this code worked (without the buffer) when i invoke texture2D within fragment shader.



but please correct me if i'm wrong, my understanding about the whole system is still weak.

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment yet, but just as a *desktop GL* remark, I can see that 1) there are no actual draw calls in your script i.e. `glDrawElements`/`glDrawArrays` (unless you've left some parts of it out), and 2) you're missing a fragment shader. Refer to e.g. [this](http://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/Tutorial#Creating_the_Shaders).

Comment: okay, i've added my fragment shader and draw function to post, there rest i've left it out.
anyway i didnt do anything complex, the code worked when i moved texture2D within fragment shader. but i dont understand why.